# Prove or disprove: if $G$ and $H$ are color critical graph then $G \vee H$ is a color critical graph

Tags: graph-theory

Prove or disprove: if $G$  and $H$ are color critical graph then  $G \vee H$ is a color critical graph

I think this is true . So let $G$ be a $k-critical $ graph and $H$ be a $p-critical$ graph. In $G\vee H$ every vertex adjacent to every vertex in $G$ so we need to introduce $p$ new colors for vertices in $H$ , thus $G \vee H$ has $k+p$ coloring.

I know that if we delete any edge or vertex in $G\vee H$ the number of coloring will reduce by 1, but I'm not sure how to explain this formally, there nothing guarantee that every vertex must have unique coloring, because the vertices in $H$ can't have the same color with the vertices in $G$ but, it can have the same color to some non adjacent vertices in $H$ , right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the case you are worried about is if the edge $uv$ is removed with $u \in G$ and $v \in H$.  In this case, we must show that the chromatic number of $G \vee H - uv$ is one less than the chromatic number of $G \vee H$.  To make this work, we need a coloring of $G$ where $u$ receives a unique color, different from the color of any other vertex in $G$.  Notice we can do this since $G$ is $k$-critical.

Specifically, $G - u$ can be colored with $k-1$ colors.  Similarly, $H - v$ can be colored with $p-1$ colors.  Hence we can color $G \vee H - \{u, v\}$ with $k+p-2$ colors, and thus we can then color $G \vee H - uv$ with $k + p - 1$ colors by coloring $u$ and $v$ with the extra color.